# How to identify Kubernetes Active Replica Pod Name

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have created a kubernetes service name is test-backend and set is  `replicas: 3` so It will create 3 podname such as

```html
test-backend-deployment-664c7d6f7f-4tnhc    1/1       Running   0          1h
test-backend-deployment-664c7d6f7f-595dc    1/1       Running   0          1h
test-backend-deployment-664c7d6f7f-dndlt    1/1       Running   0          1h
```

So how I can identify which pod is active currently ? because If I try each one like :
`kubectl logs test-backend-deployment-664c7d6f7f-4tnhc`  then I can identify which is active so Question is there is another way we can identify ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless i'm misunderstanding your question, all three pods are active. The service will round robin requests to all 3 instances (by default).

Answer (score 0):

I just want to verify which is the current pods is serving so I identify that hostname is same as podname.
Thanks I got the solution.

Comment: Could you tell me what your solution was, if you remember? I have the same doubt at this moment